# cargo build help show all found implementations

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am getting following error while compiling my project:=

```
= help: the following implementations were found:
          <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<&'static [u8]>>
          <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<&'static str>>
          <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<bytes::bytes::Bytes>>
          <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'static, [u8]>>>
        and 4 others
```

This isn't helpfull. I wanna know those 4 other implementations too. How can I tell cargo to show me them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to get cargo to show more detail in error messages like that, but for this case you can find the same information in rustdoc. If you want to see the implementations provided by hyper, you can go to the [trait implementations for Body on docs.rs](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13/hyper/struct.Body.html#trait-implementations) and note the `From` implementations there. If you also want to include implementations provided by other crates or your own code, you can use `cargo doc --open` in your crate to generate and view documentation for your project and its dependencies, and then check the trait implementations for `Body` in the same way.

Comment: I cant find documentation for `hyper::body::body::Body`. There is documentation for `hyper::body::Body` but I dont know if it's same as `hyper::body::body::Body`

Comment: They are the same type. Internally `hyper` is structured with an extra nested `body` module ([defined here](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/aac0e2dd57244d13e0972b46148fd1cbe4a9f509/src/body/mod.rs#L26)) and then `Body` is re-exported from that in the public API [here](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/aac0e2dd57244d13e0972b46148fd1cbe4a9f509/src/body/mod.rs#L22).